# error handling in data pipeline using project reactor

Tags: project-reactor, reactor, reactor-kafka

I'm writing a data pipeline using Reactor and Reactor Kafka and use spring's `Message<>` to save
the `ReceiverOffset` of `ReceiverRecord` in the headers, to be able to use `ReciverOffset.acknowledge()` when finish processing. I'm also using the out-of-order commit feature enabled.

When an event process fails I want to be able to log the error, write to another topic that represents all the failure events, and commit to the source topic. I'm currently solving that by returning `Either<Message<Error>,Message<myPojo>>` from each processing stage, that way the stream will not be stopped by exceptions and I'm able to save the original event headers and eventually commit the failed messages at the button of the pipeline.

The problem is that each step of the pipline gets `Either<>` as input and needs to filter the previous errors, apply the logic only on the Either.right and that could be cumbersome, especially when working with buffers and the operator get 'List<Either<>>' as input. So I would want to keep my business pipeline clean and get only `Message<MyPojo>` as input but also not missing errors that need to be handled.

I read that sending those message erros to other channel or stream is a soulution for that.
Spring Integration uses that pattern for error handling and I also read an article ([link to article](https://medium.com/kaizo-engineering/pure-and-type-safe-error-handling-in-akka-streams-8acacf422d45)) that solves this problem in Akka Streams using '[divertTo()](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/Source-or-Flow/divertTo.html)':

I couldn't find documentation or code examples of how to implement that in Reactor,
is there any way to use Spring Integration error channel with Reactor? or any other ideas to implement that?

Comment: Which `Either` are you using?  Functionaljava's?

Comment: From Vavr library

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with reactor per se, but you can keep the stream linear.  The trick, since Vavr's `Either` is right-biased is to use `flatMap`, which would take a function from `Message<MyPojo>` to `Either<Message<Error>, Message<MyPojo>>`.  If the `Either` coming in is a right (i.e. a `Message<MyPojo>`, the function gets invoked and otherwise it just gets passed through.

```java
// Apologies if the Java is atrocious... haven't written Java since pre-Java 8

incomingEither.flatMap(
    myPojoMessage -> ... // compute a new Either
)
```

Presumably at some point you want to do something (publish to a dead-letter topic, tickle metrics, whatever) with the `Message<Error>` case, so for that, `orElseRun` will come in handy.

Comment: In general for a consume-then-do-stuff-then-commit stream from Kafka where you want at-least-once-and-nearly-always-only-once, it's a really good idea to keep it simple with a linear flow.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! I fully agree with that if my flow is processing each event at a time and uses 'Either' features. The problem comes when i'm using batches (for DB requests etc...) Then I need to manually filter the left side of Either and then add them before the next pipeline step. That can lead to unorder the events and code overhead for each step. Luckily I'm using out-of-order commit feature, but still it seemed to me that this not the best options, what are your thoughts? Or how would you handle batch of Eithers?